# Grails 2.4 Service-Call in Controller but Service is null?

Tags: web-services, grails

This example program throws folling nullpointer Exception:

```
    2015-07-23 15:12:36,815 [http-bio-8090-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /GrailsProject/HTMLAnalyser/start
Cannot invoke method analyse() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot invoke method analyse() on null object
    Line | Method
->>   14 | start     in org.Bookstore.HTMLAnalyserController$$EPJGWngM
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

**I have this Controller:**

```
package org.Bookstore

import org.Bookstore.HTMLAnalyserService

class HTMLAnalyserController {

    def htmlAnalyserService

    def index() { }

    def start() {

        def html = "START"
        html = htmlAnalyserService.analyse()
        render html
    }

}
```

**and i have this Service:**

```
package org.Bookstore

import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class HTMLAnalyserService {

    def serviceMethod() {

    }

    def analyse() {
        println "ok"
        def map = [:]
        map.put("key", "value")
        map.put("key2", "value2")
        return map
    }
}
```

i created controller and service with grails command line tool.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that property name for a class with name `HTMLAnalyserService` is `HTMLAnalyserService` (i.e the same).

That's because `HTML` is assumed to be an acronym (because of being all uppercase) and therefore not downcased. If your class name was called `HtmlAnalyserService`, the dependency injection would indeed be done for properties named `htmlAnalyserService`.

A quick way of testing what's the correct name for dependency injection is to use the method `grails.util.GrailsNameUtils#getPropertyName` (see http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.x/api/grails/util/GrailsNameUtils.html#getPropertyName(java.lang.Class)).

```
import static grails.util.GrailsNameUtils.*
assert getPropertyName('HtmlAnalyserService') == 'htmlAnalyserService'
assert getPropertyName('HTMLAnalyserService') == 'HTMLAnalyserService'
```

You can also pass a class to it.

Answer (score -1):

i found the answer :

For Grails dependency injection to work, you need to name the variable like your class name

so for me i have to write:

```
def HTMLAnalyserService
```

instead of def htmlAnalyserService (behavior suxx)

even

```
HTMLAnalyserService xxx 
xxx.analyse()
```

not working

or

```
org.Bookstore.HTMLAnalyserService xxx
xxx.analyse()
```

not working but GGTS shows me Variable is fine

Comment: "...you need to name the variable like your class name" - Generally that is not true.  It is not the case that the variable name needs to match the class name.  It is the case that your variable name needs to match the property name representation of the class name.  For a class like `HTMLAnalyserService` it turns out that the property name representation happens to be the same as the class name, but for most classes that is no the case.  The property name representation of `HtmlAnalyserService` is `htmlAnalyserService`.  See the Java Bean spec for the rules of how to do the conversion.  HTH

Comment: The reason that `HTMLAnalyserService xxx` and `org.Bookstore.HTMLAnalyserService xxx` don't work is that by default we are imposing auto-wiring by name, not auto-wiring by type.  The name of the variable is the important part.  If you had a bean named `xxx` of type `HTMLAnalyserService` then a declaration like `HTMLAnalyserService xxx` would work.